# AMD Fakeraid and Debian?

Tags: debian, raid, amd, fakeraid

I can't get my (AMD-based) BIOS RAID to work with either Debian or Ubuntu. With my BIOS in AHCI mode, I successfully detect all drives; however, in RAID mode, all SATA drives disappear, and I can only see my NVMe card. I've set `dmraid=true`, but I still have no luck.

Anyone else have any success with AMD BIOS RAID on Debian/Debian based distros? Is this a problem with just my motherboard?

Comment: 1. What brand/model of motherboard?  does the bios display a name/version of the fakeraid when booting (if so, what is it?).   How is the fakeraid set up (raid 1? raid 5?)   3. Do you ever intend to dual boot with windows?   If not, then linux's software raid (e.g. with mdadm or lvm) is superior in **every** way to fakeraid/dmraid - the only reason to use fakeraid with linux is if you need to share the disks with windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need the appropriate chipset drivers from AMD's driver web page, if they are available. Forget the fakeraid and look into a decent raid controller from any reputable vendor if you plan to dual boot. Otherwise, if you are just running one OS, use the software raid option that is available for Linux.